# Why do certain implementations run slow in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, optimization, time-complexity, palindrome

I have three implementations of a function that checks whether a string (or a space delimited phrase) is a palindrome:

```
def palindrome(str_in):
    def p(s, i, j):
        if i >= j:
            return True
        elif s[i] != s[j]:
            return False
        else:
            return p(s, i+1, j-1)
    return p(str_in.replace(' ', '').lower(), 0, len(str_in)-1)

def palindrome1(s):
    st = s.replace(' ', '').lower()
    return st == st[::-1]

def palindrome2(s):
    st = s.replace(' ', '').lower()
    i, j = 0, len(st)-1
    while i < j:
        if st[i] != st[j]:
            return False
        else:
            i += 1
            j -= 1
    return True
```

Now, I figured `palindrome()` would be optimal in theory because no reversing and extra memory is taking place, but python does not have tail call optimization. `palindrome2()` is the imperative version of `palindrome()` but still takes much longer than `palindrome1()`. Why is this?

Here is the profiled results (ran with: `python -m cProfile file.py`):

```
         12 function calls in 45.341 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.232    0.232   45.341   45.341 file.py:1(<module>)
        1    2.198    2.198    3.532    3.532 file.py:300(palindrome1)
        1   39.442   39.442   40.734   40.734 file.py:304(palindrome2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    2.396    1.198    2.396    1.198 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.843    0.843    0.843    0.843 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
        2    0.231    0.115    0.231    0.115 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {sys.setrecursionlimit}
```

Here is the profiled results(ran with: `pypy -m cProfile hw2.py`):

```
         11 function calls in 12.470 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.011    0.011   12.470   12.470 hw2.py:1(<module>)
        1    2.594    2.594    6.280    6.280 hw2.py:303(palindrome1)
        1    0.852    0.852    4.347    4.347 hw2.py:307(palindrome2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    3.263    1.631    3.263    1.631 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
        1    1.832    1.832    1.832    1.832 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
        2    3.918    1.959    3.918    1.959 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {sys.setrecursionlimit}
```

Here is my palindrome constructor:

```
def palindrome_maker(n):
    from random import choice
    alphabet = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    front = ''.join([choice(alphabet) for _ in range(n//2)])
    back = front[::-1]
    return front + (choice(alphabet) if n%2==1 else '') + back
```

BTW: the profile shows the performance for calling the functions with a string of length `999999999`.

Comment: General rule: builtins = fast; python loops = slow.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, I understand that, but I was hoping to get a more low-level answer.

Comment: My guess is that python's list reversal is optimized and implemented as C function. If you do the same thing in python, there's more levels of abstractions you have to go through.

Comment: "`palindrome2()` ... takes much longer than `palindrome1()`" .. because `palindrome2()` executes lots of Python code, while `palindrome1()` executes very little. Things like `.reverse()`, `.replace()`, and `[::-1]` are done within the interpreter (coded in C) and are very fast.

Comment: Also, WTF is with writing `-1` as `~0`?

Comment: @ljeabmreosn: that's mostly it. palindrome1 executes just a handful of Python opcodes, and both the string reversal and the comparison are done in C. The extra memory allocation is negligible for not-so-long strings. The other implementations instead do a lot of operations in Python (which, as a rule of thumb, is normally between 1 and 2 orders of magnitude slower than equivalent C code), without changing the asymptotic behavior. So, yes, you are avoiding an extra copy, but the Python overhead is killing any advantage.

Comment: @ffledgling Is there any place where I am able to see what's going behind the scenes of Python functions?

Comment: Doesn't `s[1:][:-1]` create a new string?

Comment: @kindall yes, as I mentioned to @MatteoItalia, I understand python functions are optimized, but that does not explain anything. What specifically (lower level) is  making the code faster (how is it implemented in C)? and for the `~`, it's more readable: why turn to 1-based indexing while reading from the end of a list? consistency is key.

Comment: @kindall symmetry? `x[0] == x[~0]` instead of `x[0] == x[-1]`

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, indeed it does. Perhaps using indices is a better recursive solution than what is shown above. I'll change it, but it is a little irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @MatteoItalia thanks for the thorough explanation. I still do not understand: if the python builtins run faster by some constant, wouldn't asymptotically the better algorithm run faster in the end? How could asymptotic relation change by using a smaller constant?

Comment: @ljeabmreosn: in C is written in the obvious way, there's no algorithmic trick. The point is that C statically typed code is translated straight to machine code, which is executed directly by the CPU. Python code, instead, is compiled to bytecode, which is executed by a virtual machine written in C. Also, the extreme dinamicity of the language makes even the execution of such "elementary" opcodes a complicated (and time consuming) business. In C a sum between two integers boils down to a single machine instruction, in Python you have to decode the opcode, dispatch to the relevant routine,

Comment: I think you need to better the time complexity. reversing a whole string and comparing two strings becomes O(n). You simply cannot beat that by writing it by hand.

Comment: determine the type of the operands and do the correct thing (which is even more complicated for non-builtin types); compared to the operation that you actually have to do (sum two integers), the time is spent exclusively in the overhead.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ah okay, so the time complexity of the Python interpreter interpreting the code is interfering with the overall time complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: @ljeabmreosn: the two algorithms (palindrome1 and 2) have the same algorithmic complexity (they are both O(N)), with palindrome1 having a much smaller constant since it avoids most of the Python overhead. Unless you hit a pathological case (allocating a really big string can be time consuming), you probably cannot beat palindrome1 in Python code.

Comment: @MatteoItalia yes, and if both were written in x86 assembly, it's probable that palindrome2 would be faster because it would not need to reverse the "string". So this is just a python thing...

Comment: Yes, but what I was saying is that time complexity (as in, asymptotic complexity) is the same - the Python overhead can be (roughly) though as a constant factor for a given algorithm.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, and thus not very interesting. I bet the different runtimes would have different constant factor as well. OP only test CPython I guess.

Comment: @Sylwester: well, when you are writing a program that has to actually run in a possibility short time it is definitely interesting :-) - in my experience a big deal in Python optimization is bending the builtins to do your work instead of writing it out straight as you would do in C. Anyhow, as you suggest it would be interesting to see how PyPy fares here, it should be a piece of cake for it to JIT-compile palindrome2 to efficient machine code.

Comment: @MatteoItalia see edit in post

Comment: Hey, in `palindrome` won't the "len" part of `return p(str_in.replace(' ', '').lower(), 0, len(str_in)-1)` be wrong if `str_in` contains spaces that get removed?

Comment: @P.Pearson Originally, yes. But I changed the function to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so let's talk from the begining. CPython compiles visible text into a thing called bytecode, which is a representation that is easier for the virtual machine (i.e. the interpreter) to understand.

Both `palindrome` and `palindrome2` functions are slower then `palindrome1` because of this overhead. There's a neat module in CPython called `dis`. If you use it on a compiled function it will show its internal representation. So lets do this:

```
>>> dis.dis(palindrome)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (p)
              3 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object p at 0x01B95110, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('palindrome.<locals>.p')
             12 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             15 STORE_DEREF              0 (p)

  9          18 LOAD_DEREF               0 (p)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (str_in)
             24 LOAD_ATTR                0 (replace)
             27 LOAD_CONST               3 (' ')
             30 LOAD_CONST               4 ('')
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             36 LOAD_ATTR                1 (lower)
             39 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             42 LOAD_CONST               5 (0)
             45 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             48 LOAD_FAST                0 (str_in)
             51 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             54 LOAD_CONST               6 (1)
             57 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             58 CALL_FUNCTION            3 (3 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             61 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now let's compare this with `palindrome1` function:

```
>>> dis.dis(palindrome1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (replace)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (' ')
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                1 (lower)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             21 STORE_FAST               1 (st)

  3          24 LOAD_FAST                1 (st)
             27 LOAD_FAST                1 (st)
             30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 LOAD_CONST               4 (-1)
             39 BUILD_SLICE              3
             42 BINARY_SUBSCR
             43 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             46 RETURN_VALUE
```

So this is what CPython more or less sees (actually these are encoded into a binary form, which is irrelevant at the moment). Then the virtual machine goes through those lines and executes them one by one.

So the first obvious thing is: more lines == more time to execute. This is because each line has to be interpreted and appropriate C code has to execute. And there are a lot of lines executed in both functions other then `palindrome1` because of the loop and recursive calls. So essentially its like your trying to run few laps but Python says "no, no, no, you have to run with 20kg on your shoulders". The more laps there are (i.e. more bytecode to execude) the slower you get. Generally this performance degradation should be linear in CPython but really who knows without reading through CPython's code? I've heard that a technique called [inline caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching) was supposed to be implemented in CPython which would affect the performance alot. I don't know whether it was done or not.

Other thing is that calls in Python are expensive. There is [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for how calls should be done at the low level (i.e. push registers onto the stack and do jump). C/C++ follows it. Now Python does alot more than that. There are frames created (which can be analyzed, e.g. when exception happens), there's a max recursion check, etc. etc. All of that counts towards performance lose.

So `palindrome` function does **alot** of calls. Recursion is inefficient in Python. In particular this is the reason why `palindrome2` is faster then `palindrome1`.

The other thing is that `palindrome1` has `[::-1]` which translates into `BUILD_SLICE` call which is implemented in C. So even though it does more then necessary (there is no reason for creating another copy of the string) it is still faster then other functions simply because the intermediate layer (i.e. the bytecode) is minimal. There is no need for the compiler to waste time on bytecode interpretation.

Another important thing is that each object you create in Python has to be garbage collected. And since these objects are generally bigger then pure C objects (for example due to reference counter) than this takes more time. Ah, by the way, incrementing and decrementing reference counters also takes time. Also there's this thing called GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which acquires and releases a lock at each command so that the bytecode is thread safe. Even though it is completely unnecessary for a single threaded application. But Python doesn't know that you won't run threads at some point, it has to do that each time. This is all so that you don't have to worry about hard problems that most C/C++ coders have to deal with. :)

Now PyPy is another story. It has this neat thing inside it called JIT = Just In Time compiler. What it does it takes any Python bytecode and converts it into machine code on the fly which then is reused. So the initial call to a function has this compiling overhead, but it still is faster. Ultimately there is no bytecode at all and all functions run purely on CPU. However this doesn't mean that PyPy is as fast as a function written in C (e.g. `[::-1]`). Simply because there are lots of optimizations that are done on C level which we don't know how to implement in PyPy or any other Python interpreter. This is due to the nature of the language - it is dynamic. Now whether it is truely impossible is another story, it's not obvious at all, but at the moment we just don't know how to do this.

**tl;dr;** builtin functions (or more generally C code run in Python) are always at least as fast as equivalent pure Python code and in most cases alot faster

Comment: Thank you for going into detail!